# Connect UML classes both with connectors on the east with pst-uml (or others)

Tags: pstricks

I want to connect UML classes both on the east side with `pst-uml`. Sadly the documentation is french and `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-uml` did not help neither.

**Concept** (Dia)

[image: Concept]

**Current status** (`pst-uml`, `texlive-pstricks 2011.22586-1`)

[image: Current status]

**Source**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{pst-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(10,3)\psgrid
    \rput[r](4,1){\rnode{lorem}{
        \umlClass{LoremText}{}
    }}

    \rput[l](6,2){\rnode{ipsum}{
        \umlClass{IpsumText}{}
    }}

    \rput[l](6,1){\rnode{dolor}{
        \umlClass{DolorText}{}
    }}

    \ncEVE[armA=1]{lorem}{ipsum}
    \ncputicon{umlHerit}

    \ncline{lorem}{dolor}
    \ncputicon{umlHerit}

    \ncEXN[armA=1]{ipsum}{dolor} % update me
    \nbput[npos=0]{1}
    \naput[npos=3]{0..*}
    \naput{do sth.}
    \ncputicon{umlAgreg}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Please ignore the multiplicity (above/below line), because I did not adjust it on the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the `ipsum` to `dolor` node connection to

```
\ncEXN[armA=1,angleB=0]{ipsum}{dolor} % update me
```

[image]

The node connection between `ipsum` and `dolor` is given by `\ncangles` with default options `angleA=0` and `angleB=-90`. The above code overrides the latter angle (`angleB`) to `0`, making the connection enter "from the east side."

For completeness, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-uml}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-uml
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(10,3)\psgrid
\rput[r](4,1){\rnode{lorem}{
    \umlClass{LoremText}{}
}}

\rput[l](6,2){\rnode{ipsum}{
    \umlClass{IpsumText}{}
}}

\rput[l](6,1){\rnode{dolor}{
    \umlClass{DolorText}{}
}}

\ncEVE[armA=1]{lorem}{ipsum}
\ncputicon{umlHerit}

\ncline{lorem}{dolor}
\ncputicon{umlHerit}

\ncEXN[armA=1,angleB=0]{ipsum}{dolor} % update me
\nbput[npos=0]{1}
\naput[npos=3]{0..*}
\naput{do sth.}
\ncputicon{umlAgreg}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-uml}
\def\UML[#1](#2)#3#4{\rput[#1](#2){\rnode{#3}{#4}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}%[showgrid]
  (10,3)
    \UML[r](4,1){lorem}{\umlClass{LoremText}{}}
    \UML[l](6,2.5){ipsum}{\umlClass{IpsumText}{}}
    \UML[l](6,1){dolor}{\umlClass{DolorText}{}}
    \ncEVE[armA=1]{lorem}{ipsum}
    \ncputicon{umlHerit}
    \ncline{lorem}{dolor}
    \ncputicon{umlHerit}
    \ncEXN[armA=1,angleB=0]{ipsum}{dolor}
    \naput[npos=0.6]{1}
    \nbput[npos=3]{0..*}
    \naput{do sth.}
    \ncputicon{umlAgreg}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helpful answers. I did some research after i understood the usage of `angleA` and `angleB` and now i know the trick:

To get the desired result i just have to replace

```
\ncEXN[armA=1]{ipsum}{dolor} % update me
```

with

```
\ncEVW[armA=1]{admin}{customer}
```

because of: `EVW` means `draw right (East) then vertical (Vertical) then left (West)`. The codes represent the relative draw direction to two objects and not the connector positions.

It is easier to understand when looking at the definition (eg. `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-uml`) in :

```
\newpsobject{ncEVW}{ncangles}{angleA=0,angleB=0}
```

Comment: Since you have received some response in addition to your own, that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). Note that in case of a self-answer [one *has* to wait 48 hours (after the question was posted) before accepting](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).